# Diffie-Hellman min key size for different browsers

Tags: security, ssl, browser-support, mod-ssl, transport-security

I am interested in whether there is somewhere described what is the min size of Diffie-Hellman key that is supported for each browser.

As I know modern browsers don't allow this key to be downgraded to 512 key size.

As example latest chrome is support 2048 keys and I am not sure if it's support 1024 key size.
Could you please share like a table browser version and min/max key size ?

And an additional question if on apache key will have 2048 length what browsers won't be able to use this key ?

Comment: Note that many browsers have recently changed (or are planning to soon change) their minimum DH key lengths due to the publication of the [logjam attack](http://blog.cryptographyengineering.com/2015/05/attack-of-week-logjam.html). Thus, right now, exact browser version is likely to make a big difference.

Comment: Yeah that's is my interest what's the browsers are affected to this kind of attack. And If we setup on server 2048 key length whether all browser corretly will work with this configuration.